Why does sp_blitz recommend backing up TDE certificate every 30 days
I was wondering why sp_blitz is recommending to back up TDE certificates that has not been backed up the last 30 days? If the certificate hasn't been changed, and it has been backed up after creation, is there a need to do more backups?
Should I do regular backups of the TDE certificates even if they have not changed since last backup?

Because shops typically delete files older than X days, and one of the files they may be deleting would be your TDE certificate.
Since TDE cert backups are so critical, and they can be backed up so quickly, why would you not back it up at least once every 30 days?

Good point. I'll go and triple check that the backups are still there (and maybe set up a more regular backup).
